# if password is incorrect then login attempts store into database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security

I am a beginner in spring security.

I have implement UserDetailsService `interface` of method `public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)`
My problem is below.......

username and password both are entered wrong then it can work properly. but when I enter the correct username and incorrect password then I want to add an attempt in the database otherwise not. if the username and password are correct then I don't want to update attempt into the database.

```
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
int MIN_ATTEMPTS = 0;
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {
        Members members = membersDao.findByEmail(email);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        if (members == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid username and password");
        } else {
            if (members == null) {

            } else {
                MIN_ATTEMPTS = members.getAttempts();
                MIN_ATTEMPTS ++;
                members.setAttempts(MIN_ATTEMPTS);
                membersDao.save(members);
                throw new RuntimeException("Login Attepmts "+MIN_ATTEMPTS);
            }
            if (members.getAttempts() <= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                Role role = members.getRoles();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
                return new User(members.getEmail(), members.getPassword(),authorities);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("blocked");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: First of all, your if-else-if-else structure is kind of weird and unstructured. This is highly unreadable and may lead to bugs. Second, you load by email and then, regardless of any passowrd provided call `membersDao.save(members)`, so why shouldn't the code attempt to store the value if you tell it to?

Comment: I want to store login fail attempt and check if login fail attempt is more then three then user is blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive tryed to change your Code a bit

```
  private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserAndCheckLogin(String email, String enteredPassword) {
    Members members = membersDao.findByEmail(email);
    if (members == null) {
      //Create Error Message for User
      return null;
    }
    if (members.getAttempts() > MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
      //Create Error Message for User
      return null;
    }
    if (members.getPassword().equals(enteredPassword)) {
      Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
      Role role = members.getRoles();
      authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
      members.setAttempts(0);
      membersDao.save(members);
      return new User(members.getEmail(), members.getPassword(), authorities);
    } else {
      int attempts = members.getAttempts();
      members.setAttempts(++attempts);
      membersDao.save(members);
      //Create Error Message for User
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Btw. im not sure if you realy want to create a new "SimpleGrantedAuthority" and "User" or if you want to load existing ones from your Database.

And you should use a hash for your Passwords.

```
Login controller
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginMembers loginMembers) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginMembers.getEmail(),
                        loginMembers.getPassword()
                )
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(authentication);
        logger.info("You are log in successfully with token");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthTokenRequest(token));
    }
```

Comment: public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) this is In-built method of  UserDetailsService interface. we cant change there signature

Comment: Oh okay, maby you should do all the checks in the calling Method then.
A Method called "load...." shouldnt check much

Comment: how to do please tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

I have customize your code and  add into calling Method as per you suggest @Pitzas 
thanks for suggest me............

```
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginMembers loginMembers) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Members members = membersDao.findByEmail(loginMembers.getEmail());
        PasswordEncoder passencoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        if (members == null) {
            //Create Error Message for User
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Username and Password");
        }
        if (members.getAttempts() >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            //Create Error Message for User
            throw new RuntimeException("Login Attempt exceeds "+MAX_ATTEMPTS);
        }

        if (passencoder.matches(loginMembers.getPassword(), members.getPassword())) {
            final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            loginMembers.getEmail(),
                            loginMembers.getPassword()
                    )
            );

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(authentication);
            logger.info("You are log in successfully with token");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthTokenRequest(token));
        } else {
            int attempts = members.getAttempts();
            members.setAttempts(++attempts);
            membersDao.save(members);
            //Create Error Message for User
            throw new RuntimeException("Login attempts "+attempts);
        }
    }
```